# I downloaded the dSYM-file but the Crashlytics does not see it

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric, dsym

I downloaded the dSYM-file but the Crashlytics does not see it. I took the file from App Store and downloaded it using "Fabric/upload-symbols". Please tell me what could be the reason

command for upload-symbols (terminal):

```
~/prjPath/ios/Pods/Fabric/upload-symbols -gsp ~/prjPath/ios/prj/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios ~/dSYMPath/69c5e6e8-fbf8-3848-82db-96b1e29f594f.dSYM
```

response:

```
Successfully submitted symbols for architecture arm64 with UUID 69c5e6e8fbf8384882db96b1e29f594f in dSYM: /dSYMPath/69c5e6e8-fbf8-3848-82db-96b1e29f594f.dSYM
```

Successfully uploaded Crashlytics symbols

[Terminal and Crashlytics console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9rWA.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

When uploading the dSYMs through [Fabric.io](https://fabric.io), they require you to compress/zip the folder first. If you haven't already, I'd give that a try first. If that fails, there is another option, if you need to proceed...

You can add your dSYM's through the Fabric Crashlytics dashboard at [fabric.io](https://fabric.io). Click the Settings cog on the top right of the page and then select apps from the menu. From there select your App from your list of apps, and you'll see another tab bar menu on the page with Missing DSYMS on the right. Compress/zip your folder before uploading, and by the time you've navigated back to the dash, they'll be ready to go.